# update SQL Server columns using XML file

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-update

I can correctly insert data into my tables using an XML file, but no I want to know if I can update columns using an XML file. 
I have this to insert, which works:

```
IF @LAST_Question <> @QuestionText
BEGIN
    insert into [TempDataBase].[dbo].TestQuestion (QuestionType, Question_Text, Questionaire_ID, Filter)
    VALUES (@QuestionType, @QuestionText, @Questionaire_ID,@Filter)

    select @newQuestion_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END 

INSERT INTO [TempDataBase].[dbo].TestPossible(Q_ID, Expl, Rev, P_A_T, QType)
VALUES (@newQuestion_ID,  @RequiresExplanation, @ReviewRequired, @Value,   @QuestionType)

SET @LAST_Question = @QuestionText
```

But when I try and update, it will only take the last value in the XML

```
UPDATE [TempDataBase].[dbo].TestPossible
SET Expl = @RequiresExplanation,
    Rev = @ReviewRequired, 
    P_A_T = @Value, 
    QType = @QuestionType
WHERE Q_ID = @ID
```

Now I do have a cursor defined and other statements to make the insert and update to run so there is no need to suggest I add those, I didn't add them to save the congestion on the page. I can show the XML if I need to. The main thing is I have multiple @Value and its only inserting the first one the required amount of times(two for the first question and three for the second) in the update

Does anyone have a suggestion to accomplish this?

EDIT: ADDED the XML

```
<Questions>
   <Question>
        <ID>2422</ID>
       <QuestionText>Did the Update Work correctly?</QuestionText>
       <QuestionType>1</QuestionType>
       <QuestionaireID>2</QuestionaireID>
       <Filter>31</Filter>
       <PossibleAnswers>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>yes it did</Value>
                     <RequiresExplanation>1</RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire>t</ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>no it did not</Value>
                       <RequiresExplanation>1</RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire>t</ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
       </PossibleAnswers>
   </Question>
   <Question>
        <ID>2423</ID>
       <QuestionText>How are you today?</QuestionText>
       <QuestionType>1</QuestionType>
       <QuestionaireID>2</QuestionaireID>
         <Filter>127</Filter>
       <PossibleAnswers>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>Great</Value>
                      <RequiresExplanation></RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire></ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>Good</Value>
                        <RequiresExplanation>1</RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire>t</ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>Bad</Value>
                       <RequiresExplanation>1</RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire>t</ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
       </PossibleAnswers>
   </Question>
</Questions>
```

and here is how I'm getting the XML data

```
DECLARE @XmlString as XML

select @XmlString = cast(x as XML)
from openrowset(bulk 'C:\xml_ID.xml',single_blob) as T(x)

--SET UP A CURSOR to walk through the uploaded XML table
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL for 
       SELECT
              Question_ID = XTBL .value('(../../ID)[1]', 'bigint'), 
              QuestionText =  XTbl.value('(../../QuestionText)[1]', 'varchar(200)'),
              QuestionType =  XTbl.value('(../../QuestionType)[1]', 'bigint'),
              Questionaire_ID =  XTbl.value('(../../QuestionaireID)[1]', 'bigint'),
              Filter =  XTbl.value('(../../Filter)[1]', 'bigint'),
              Value = XTbl.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(400)'),
              RequiresExplanation = XTbl.value('(RequiresExplanation)[1]', 'int'),
              ReviewRequired =  XTbl.value('(ReviewRequire)[1]', 'char(1)')
       FROM
           @XmlString.nodes('/Questions/Question/PossibleAnswers/PossibleAnswer') AS XD(XTbl)
```

Comment: need the xml file and how the values are extracted from the xml code

Comment: @RADAR is this what you need?

Comment: looks good, where ID set that is used in the update statement, where is this ID modified ?

Comment: @RADAR Well I am hoping to get it from the XML, because that ID is the ID from the question table that corresponds to those answers..did I word that right? and I just noticed its getting the last values in the XML file

Comment: as question id is same for all values, it will keep updating the same value , so only last value is retained, you need a kEY to indicate the value , you might be better of using a auto increment ID in that table, so atlest you can update the values in that order if that is what you want.

Comment: @RADAR So there would be no way without the Primary key from the answers table?

Comment: @user33222270, another option is remove all the Values corresponding to that question id and insert the new values.

Comment: No you were right, I thought it might be that but was hoping it wouldn't, Don't know how to give you credit though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update to the table `TestPossible` is done using Question_ID

if we take the sample input below, there are two values for the same question id and only one row i.e. last row is matching and getting updated.

```
Question_ID Value
2422    "yes it did"
2422    "no it did not"
```

One option is to remove all the rows for the questions and update new possible values
or you need to have another unique key to identify individual possible answer value.